Report generation using Fast Report with .Net Core 8
I'm developing a .NET Core application in which I use FastReport to generate reports in PDF format.
I am providing a .frx file and a .json file, which acts as a data source compatible with the .frx file as a parameter. However, while binding data, it shows the static data used during the design of the .frx file instead of binding the dynamic data provided in the JSON file. Additionally, it should be capable of binding databands and child bands.
Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Here are a few snippets I've tried:
// Load the report
var report = new Report();
report.Load("path_to_your.frx");

// Load the JSON data
var jsonData = File.ReadAllText("path_to_your.json");

// Base64 encode the JSON data
string encodedJsonData = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData));

// Register the JSON data source connection
RegisteredObjects.AddConnection(typeof(JsonDataSourceConnection));
JsonDataSourceConnection jsonDataSourceConnection = new JsonDataSourceConnection
{
    Name = "Connection",
    ConnectionString = $"Json={encodedJsonData};Encoding=utf-8"
};

// Create all tables from the JSON data
jsonDataSourceConnection.CreateAllTables(true);
report.Dictionary.Connections.Add(jsonDataSourceConnection);

// Prepare the report
 if (report.Prepare())
{
    FastReport.Export.Pdf.PDFExport export = new FastReport.Export.Pdf.PDFExport();
    export.ShowProgress = false;
    export.Subject = "Report Subject";
    export.Title = "Report Title";
    System.IO.MemoryStream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    report.Report.Export(export, memStream);
    report.Dispose();
    export.Dispose();
    memStream.Position = 0;

    return File(memStream, "application/pdf", "Report_" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".pdf");
}


You should share a sample of report and code.

Took a bit of digging. I could not locate the answer in any single place, but the OP tipped me off with the report.Dictionary.Connections. In my case I have a single connection in my report and updating the existing Connection with the JSON to the ConnectionString allowed the data to be repopulated.
public async Task CreateCustomerExportPdfAsync()
{
    var customers = await GetCustomersAsync();

    var assembly = GetType().Assembly;

    // Added the report as an Embedded Resource
    using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name!}.Test.frx"))
    { 
        var pdf = new PDFSimpleExport();
        var report = new Report();
        report.Load(stream);

        var builder = new JsonDataSourceConnectionStringBuilder();
        // Simple wrapper to a json serializer such as newtonsoft
        builder.Json = _jsonService.SerializeToString(customers);

        // We only have one connection, take it and update
        // the 'connectionstring' which is actually the data
        // Adding a custom dictionary does not seem to register
        // however selecting the existing one seems to work just
        // fine.
        var connection = report.Dictionary.Connections[0];
        connection.ConnectionString = builder.ToString();

        await report.PrepareAsync();

        // Exporting to a temp directory
        report.Export(pdf, "C:\\temp\\test.pdf");
    }
}

